# Django static folder with css and javascript wont load

Tags: python, css, django

Hey I have a problem with the static files directory in Django,

Inside the html template I already used the `{% load static %}` above the link tag and in the link tag I used

`href="{% static 'style.css' %}"` (keep in mind the style.css is in the static folder which is located in the projects root folder (after several times "still not working" I even created the same static folder with the same css file in the respective app folder... and still not working).

In the settings.py I used all of the following lines one at a time and even all together

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static")

STATIC_DIRS = (
    '/static',
)
```

the html renders perfectly fine and is showing in the browser without any errors but for whatever reason the styling just wont apply (internal and inline sytling works, but I want to use external css). There seems to be a problem in the settings.py file but since I gave the path to the static folder in any way possible, I really don't know what to do. I didnt try with .js files yet but it'll be the same problem I guess.

I'm thankfull for any answer.

Comment: Did you add the media and static views to the `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0):

***Add to urls.py***

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```